# print child's of the current term with hierarchy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

just terms. No nodes...

For example

we have this structure:

Fruits

-yellow

--banana

-red

--apple

--strawberry

Vegetables

-green

-red

-orange

But, if user now in term page **Fruits -> Yellow**, need to print only child's for **yellow**

Comment: A simple solution would be a view at path `/taxonomy/term/%`, add a contextual filter on `Taxonomy term: Parent term` with default value of `Taxonomy term ID from URL`. On Fruits you'll see Yellow and Red, on Yellow you'll see Banana. It's very simple but not recursive.

Comment: Ben: Yes, But need print all childs with hierarchy tree...